error bound for the approximation of hypergeometric to binomial distribuition
I am trying to find a way to bound the error of the approximation mentioned. So far, I followed the steps of a proof to the convergence from hypergeometric to binomial leading to the following result.
$$
|H(N,K,n)(x) - B(K/N,n)(x)|\leq\left|\prod_{i=1}^x\frac{K-x+i}{N-x+i}\,\prod_{j=1}^{n-x}\frac{N-K-n+x+j}{N-n+j} - \left(\frac{K}{N}\right)^x\left(\frac{N-K}{N}\right)^{n-x}\right|
$$
From that, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that

$\left|\frac{i-x}{N}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1-x}{N}\right|<\varepsilon$
$\left|\frac{x-n-j}{N}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x-n-1}{N}\right|<\varepsilon$
$\left|\frac{j-n}{N}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1-n}{N}\right|<\varepsilon$

That would give some bound for the first product and $(K/N)^x$; and some bound for the second product and $(1-K/N)^{n-x}$. Then, those bounds would give another one for the whole thing.
I dont know really how to find them or even if it is a good approach.
